# How trim() works in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `SysTraNo` with some specific data like

```
HO/20-21/DRP/0001
215/21-22/AGP/0003
```

I want to trim that whole column and only take `20-21` or `21-22` of that data. How can I do this?

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING('HO/20-21/DRP/0001', CHARINDEX('/', 'HO/20-21/DRP/0001')+1, 5) AS res;`

Comment: What makes you think this has something to do with trimming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the base string functions we can try:

```sql
SELECT val,
       SUBSTRING(val,
                 CHARINDEX('/', val) + 1,
                 CHARINDEX('/', val, CHARINDEX('/', val) + 1) -
                     CHARINDEX('/', val) - 1) AS nums
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The logic here is to take a substring starting from the character after the *first* `/` until the character before the *second* `/`.  On other databases, we could have used regular expressions, but SQL Server has no native support for this.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server trim works like below.
As one example is above Here I have given another example using substring on email to extract the domain part.

SELECT
email,
SUBSTRING(
email,
CHARINDEX('@', email)+1,
LEN(email)-CHARINDEX('@', email)
) domain
FROM
practice
ORDER BY
email;

[image]